# Not getting a notification of only one of my contacts

Tags: notifications

I have the problem of not getting notified of only one of my contacts message but the moon isn't there

Answer (score 1):

Most likely the Hide Alerts option has been enabled for this contact.

Open the Messages app, tap on the contact's chat whom you are unable to receive notification from and then tap on the i icon at the top right corner of your screen.

On the next screen toggle Off the Hide Alerts option.